# Need to change IP address after assigning to webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, webdriver

Hi I am creating a automation tool for a scheduling platform using selenium chrome webdriver in python. I can use perfectly static or residential authentication proxy with the chrome driver by creating as extension.

Now my needs is I want to change the IP address/proxy in the runtime without close the driver. So my question is; Is there any way to change IP runtime without closing the driver, Or there are any Ip provider who can solve my use cases.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see you basically want to rotate proxies. You can look into the os module, time module & random module. It can help you loop through a proxies.txt file containing all your ips and you can specify when you want the ip to change

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).